# how do I set html5Mode in angular unit test? using karma

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

Ok I have spent a couple hours on this one...

I cant figure out how to set html5Mode in a angular unit test.

Here is my Karma config from my Gruntfile.js. [Gruntfile conf](http://pastebin.com/4eNvY0nw)

Here is my unit test spec file: [Unit Test File](http://pastebin.com/gy418eSR) (SEE LINE 26)

So I tried running the unit test from the Angular documentation at [ANgularJS documentation for $location URL here]    (section "HTML5 mode") this is the spec file:

PASTEBIN DOT COM SLASH SQFr8Y7i

When I run that ^^ spec file I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $locationProviderProvider <- $locationProvider
```

I am trying to make unit tests that test when html5Mode is on and off.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :

```
angular.module('testModule', []).config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

describe('module', function() {

    beforeEach(module(
        'testModule'
    ));

    it('should test url', function() {

    });
});
```

But do you really need to activate this feature in a **unit test** ?

Comment: well like I said I want to have my app work in both html5 mode enabled AND disabled, so I need unit tests for both enabled/disabled modes.

Comment: also there are directives that should work in both html4 and html5 mode so i want to test that.

Comment: Well ok. You can activate/desactivate it with the example I gave you

Comment: Bixi, this works, but the new problem now is that it wipes out any directives that my app has. I have a file called directives.js with something like "angular.module('MyAppModule').directive('activeNav', ['$location', function($location) { ... }" This directive does not load anymore in the test after using your code above. How do I include this directive? It is this directive that I am trying to test with html5 mode on/off.

Comment: I just gave you an example, you have to inject your own dependencies now (in the beforeEach), and don't forget to load your JS files in your karma config file

Comment: Bixi, maybe you misunderstood my question, but I have been trying to use the code that you gave me in my unit test, and I am not able to set html5 mode to a custom value in my unit test. The "angular.module" call in my test code re-creates a my app module. Also, if you look at http://andyshora.com/unit-testing-best-practices-angularjs.html#comment-1092543887 you will see that "You would never use angular.module('yourApp')". So, I am left with the option of splitting my tests into multiple spec files.

Comment: Bixi, my goal is to have my app work in both html 5 mode enabled and disabled. On one server it will work in html5 mode, and on another server it will be html4 mode. So, to test this how do I do that? I tried your code multiple times.. not working. I looked at this: http://quickleft.com/blog/angularjs-unit-testing-for-real-though where the app modules directives and services are made into their own separate modules. Please help. I did see a lot of examples of how people test angular and found this: http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/07/ng-improved-testing-mock-testing-for-angularjs-made-easy/

Comment: Bixi, also my Karma config file is set up so that my main app JS code is loaded, so the angular.module call is made in those files and those files define the module.